# How to trim video and get output in Laravel ffmpeg?

Tags: php, laravel, video, ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg in local and imported in controller as well

```
public function trimmer(Request $request){
        $files=$request->file('files');
        if($files){
            foreach($files as $video){
                $filename= $video->getClientOriginalName();
                $extension = $video->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileNameToStore = time().'_'.$filename;
                $path = 
             $video>storeAs('/public/videos',$fileNameToStore);
                $videoArray[]=$fileNameToStore;

            }
$media=FFMpeg::open('public/videos'.'/'.$videoArray[0])
            ->filters()
            ->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(1), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(60));

        return view('video',compact('media'));
    }
```

In the above code I am getting the array of videos. How can I trim each video which length is more than 1 minute?

For now `videoArray` has only one file, that's why I used `$videoArray[0]` for instance.

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: i am not getting any output in video player, first i want to know, is above code has any mistake, if not then how can i access the output

Comment: Which video player are you talking about? The given code tries to trim some videos, not to play any

Comment: i mean normal video or iframe tag, where  i can see output in blade

Comment: have you tried passing the variable $media inside the video tag that html provides

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it - what do you mean by "see output in blade"? Your question does not contain any templating code

Comment: yes sir, i already did  that